# How can I reshape the dataframe for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot this dataframe using ggplot. Basically, a correlation plot between value1 and value2, but two facets (long>75 and long<75). I am not sure how to reshape the data using this condition. Could you please help? I have only done straight plotting in ggplot till now without reshape.

```
num fips    gauge   lat         long        value1    value2 
357 25021   1105600 42.19028    -70.94528   2.8034      3.94
358 25021   1105600 42.19028    -70.94528   12.9691     4.32
359 25021   1103500 42.25611    -70.26056   41.6258     7.99
357 25021   1105600 42.19028    -75.94528   7.8034      11.33
358 25021   1105600 42.19028    -75.94528   14.9691     14.64
359 25021   1103500 42.25611    -75.26056   43.6258     23.44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is a bit misleading as I don't see any need in reshaping the data here.
All you need to do is just round the "long" variable and plot it as is (assuming `dat` is your data)

```
dat$long <- floor(dat$long)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ long, scales = "free")
```

[image]

If your data isn't representive, you could create a dummy variable and then put it into `facet_wrap` instead of `long`, something like

```
dat$long2 <- ifelse(dat$long < -75, "< -75", "> -75")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ long2, scales = "free")
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Testing.